# Name convention for unwrapped value in Swift

Tags: swift

When I unwrap a value in Swift, I'm always uncertain on how to name the variabile which will contain it:

```
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let unwrappedTouches = touches
    {
        ....
    }

}
```

Is there some *popular-among-Swift-coders* naming convention?

Comment: Please don't do this, we finally got rid of polish notation. And it will be hard to comprehend when lot's of vars begin with `unwrapped` and the other half with `optional`. You are planning on balanced naming, right?  Then perhaps we should add polish naming for var and let, perhaps `mutable` and `immutable`. So: `mutableOptionalX` and `immutableWrappedY`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can assign the same name to an unwrapped variable as the optional.
**Preferred:**

```
var subview: UIView?
var volume: Double?

// later on...
if let subview = subview, let volume = volume {
  // do something with unwrapped subview and volume
}
```

**Not preferred:**

```
var optionalSubview: UIView?
var volume: Double?

if let unwrappedSubview = optionalSubview {
  if let realVolume = volume {
    // do something with unwrappedSubview and realVolume
  }
}
```

Taken from [The Official raywenderlich.com Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#optionals).
However these are just guidelines and other conventions may be just fine.

Comment: Absolutely didn't know that you can use the same name!.. was it possibile also in Swift 1?

Comment: It is possible in Swift 1.2, however I don't know about Swift 1.0.

Comment: Also `if var subview = subview`

Comment: Yes, one has always been able to use the same name.

Comment: I'm wondering, does this create another variable that happens to have the same name (but not the same scope), or is it a kind of re-assignment? Maybe I'm still thinking too much in terms of pointers.

Comment: This creates a new variable which overshadows the existing one. As you cannot create two equally named variables in the same scope, you cannot use the same name when using a guard statement if the optional variable is declared in the same scope. Optional parameters to a function can however be replaced using a guard statement using an equally named non-optional variable in the function.

Comment: I wonder why Swift hasn't introduced a shortcut yet, like `if let subview!, let volume!`

Comment: what if you're using a value if it exists, and then you have to update it? 
`var temp: Int? = nil; if let myTemp = temp { do something with myTemp; temp = newValue }`

you can't use let var temp = temp here because if you mutate temp it's mutating the unwrapped copy, not the original temp

Answer (score 3):

One may also use `guard-let` construct to unwrap optionals. However, `guard` creates a new variable which will exist outside the else statement so the naming options available for the unwrapped variable is different when compared to `if-let` construct.

Refer the code example below:

```
import Foundation

let str = Optional("Hello, Swift")

func sameName_guard() {
    // 1. All Good
    // This is fine since previous declaration of "str" is in a different scope
    guard let str = str else {
        return
    }

    print(str)
}

func differentName_guard() {
    let str1 = Optional("Hello, Swift")
    // 2. ERROR
    // This generates error as str1 is in the same scope
    guard let str1 = str1 else {
        return
    }

    print(str1)
}

sameName_guard()
differentName_guard()
```