# Unwrapping naming convention

Tags: swift, swift2, naming-conventions, convention, unwrap

I was wondering if there is a naming convention to unwrap optional values.

```
var x: Int? = 0

if let x = x {
}
// OR ?
if let _x = x {
}
```

Lots of blogs articles are using the first case.

But if I refer to the [WWDC 2014 session 402 (Introduction to Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-402/) Apple is using :

```
if let legCount = possibleLegCount {
    println("An aardvark has \(legCount) legs")
}
```

So is there an official convention at this time ?

Comment: I would consider that as "primarily opinion based". The same question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192828/name-convention-for-unwrapped-value-in-swift?rq=1 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186448/naming-convention-for-optional-binding

Comment: Thanks for your links.