# In Swift 5.7+ why is `if let name = name { }` preferred instead of `if let newName { }`?

Tags: swift

I’m coming back to Swift after several years. I had a situation at work recently where I thought I was being pushed to reuse variable names. I followed an `if let` example from the latest edition of Apple’s Swift manual in which a new variable name is created. I was told that the community as a whole has opted to reuse variable names. I’m curious why this preferred and why declaring a new name is frowned upon. Understanding the logic behind this would help me understand why I should do it this way (after all, I’m coming from years of TypeScript where this is not OK).

Example from Swift manual:

```
if let name = optionalName { … }
```

Standard way:

```
if let name = name { … }
```

Comment: As per my understanding, reusing the same name is preferred to avoid confusion because these unwrapped variables are just shadows of the original. Also from Swift 5.7, you can also use if let shorthand for unwrapping optionals. That will look like: `if let name { ... }` instead of `if let name = name { ... }`

Comment: Can you give a link to the code you found in the Swift book? I would have expected them to use `if let name { ... }` instead.

Comment: I also prefer the way mentioned in @Sweeper's comment.  Next i prefer using same name because it is easier to use one name rather than two. Someone might argue  saying it creates confusion between two variables but the newly created variable is valid only inside the if let scope. So no big issue

Comment: "I’m curious why this preferred and why declaring a new name is frowned upon." declaring a new name isn't frowned upon. Naming variables, including naming unwrapped optionals is all very subjective, so there are no cut and dry rules. In some scenarios there's no need to create a variable with a different name, but in some scenarios unwrapping to a different variable might provide more meaning. In general though, the main reason for reusing variable names when unwrapping is conciseness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most common reason is that these are common guidelines, such as mentioned in the official [Ray Wenderlich Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/kodecocodes/swift-style-guide#optionals).

I also believe this is preferred by Apple/Swift itself given proposal [SE-0345](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0345-if-let-shorthand.md) with shorthand for shadowing existing optional variables, which was introduced in Swift 5.7.

Edit:
Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32192915/406677

Comment: Thanks for this and for linking the discussions. This was exactly what I was looking for. I didn’t know that this was called “shadowing” and that it was discussed in these places (which is why I posted this question to begin with).

Answer (score 1):

> I’m curious why this preferred and why declaring a new name is frowned upon.

It isn't. You can still do

```
if let newName = name { ... }
```

and it is probably the most appropriate thing to do in some places. For example,

```
let optiionalFoo: String? = ...

...

if let foo = optionalFoo { ... }
```

It's up to you.

Prior to [SE 345](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0345-if-let-shorthand.md), people were finding that they were writing

```
if let foo = foo { ... }
```

quite a lot. The new syntax was introduced as a shorthand for the above, nothing more, although it does appear to magically change an optional to a non optional, particularly when used with `guard`. It doesn't *actually* change the variable, it shadows the original with a new non optional "copy".

Use it or don't use it depending on your preference or your project's style guide.

Comment: "although it does appear to magically change an optional to a non optional": It doesn't change it, it creates a new non-optional constant and copies the value of the optional reference.

Comment: @PaulPeelen That is why I said "appear". It actually creates a new local `let` that shadows the original.

Comment: Exactly, it does not appear to magically change an optional to a non optional, it appears to create a new constant that shadows the original. 

Comment: @PaulPeelen but if you were new to Swift and unaware of the mechanism, it seems like that is what happens.